# Paperclip images disappear after capistrano deploy ALTHOUGH symlinked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, capistrano, spree

my paperclip images in a spree commerce project disappear after a capstrano deploy. I tried symlinking them in the deploy.rb file but there might be a mistake with it? Anyhow I've been on this for a whole day now. I feel like the symlink should be sufficient. I also called build_missing_paperclip_styles.

image.rb from spree:

```
has_attached_file :attachment,
                      default_url: ':rails_root/public/missing.png',
                      styles: { mini: '80x80>', small: '100x100>', product: '640x640>', large: '640x640>' },
                      default_style: :product,
                      url: '/spree/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension',
                      path: ':rails_root/public/spree/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension',
                      convert_options: { all: '-strip -auto-orient -colorspace sRGB' }
```

deploy.rb:

```
 namespace :deploy do
   task :start do ; end
   task :stop do ; end
   task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
     run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
   end
    desc "build missing paperclip styles"

  task :build_missing_paperclip_styles, :roles=> :app do
      run "cd #{current_path}; RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles"
    end

  task :saveme, :roles => :app do
    run "rm -rf #{release_path}/public/spree && mkdir -p #{ deploy_to }/shared/spree"
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/spree #{release_path}/public/spree"
  end
 end


after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:saveme"
after "deploy", "deploy:build_missing_paperclip_styles"
after "deploy", "deploy:restart"
after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"
```

any ideas? - pics simply disappear after a new deploy to production

when deploying with capistrano, the commands get executed for sure:

```
* 2014-06-05 23:21:26 executing `deploy:saveme'
  * executing "rm -rf /home/deploy/releases/20140605211204/public/spree && mkdir -p /home/deploy/shared/spree"
    servers: []
    [] executing command
    command finished in 160ms
  * executing "ln -nfs /home/deploy/shared/spree /home/deploy/releases/20140605211204/public/spree"
    servers: []
    [] executing command
    command finished in 159ms
```